# fileChannel.lock not working expectedly

Tags: java, file, operating-system, nio

I am using [**`fileChannel.lock(long position, long size, boolean shared)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29) to get an exclusive access of a particular portion of the file. The exact code is:

```
fileChannel.lock(3458, 128, false);
```

But unfortunately when i am trying to change something any where in the file from a different process it is throwing exception saying that the file is locked. But my expectation was it should allow me to change any part of the file apart from the portion which i have locked.

Can somebody help me in finding what am i doing wrong?

---

Some of the details about my setup:

**OS details:**

```
Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5
```

**Processes details:**

1. java process which locks the particular portion of the file
2. **TextWrangler** which tries to change the file in different portion than that of the locked portion. But it fails.

Comment: TextWrangler is probably trying to overwrite the entire file.

Comment: @EJP i am replacing one char by another. And it says the file is locked hence can't do the operation. Thanks.

Comment: TextWrangler is still probably trying to overwrite the entire file. That's what most text editors do. The evidence here suggests it. Do you have some evidence to the contrary?

Answer (score 1):

The `FileChannel.lock` methods are highly OS dependent. Moreover, you don't get any file locking on unix platforms. That's why it might not work on Mac OS X as this is unix based.

Comment: Does the Java library not use `flock()`?

Comment: I think they use `fcntl()` on linux. Not sure about mac.